# Jquery element innerXml

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following simple xml:

```
<xmldoc>
    <first><node></node></first>
</xmldoc>
```

I want to select a given node and get the inner xml text.

```
$(xml).find('xmldoc').**OuterXMLFunctionThatNotExists**()="<first><node></node></first>"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`var text = $(xml).html();`

It works in chrome

**EDIT**: let xml be text and not an xml file because jquery will then treat it as new html element. (like document.createElement() )

`var text = $("<xmldoc>
    <first><node></node></first>
</xmldoc>").html();`

Or i guess you are getting it from an ajax call? Then don't set dataType to xml (jQuery) or use XHR.responseText

you will get only text and text can easily be parsed with jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

try this-

`var text = $(xml).find('xmldoc').text();`

Comment: With this i would get the text of the nodes not the whole xml.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $(xml).find('xmldoc').parent().text();
```